# I want to fetch some info from a webpage in android studio

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to fetch sometitle and somelink from HTML code below for my android app ...
HELP ME :(

```
<div class="proper-list list-group page-cat-wrap">
  <figure class="col-md-12 thumb-vertical">
  <div class="col-xs-4 thumb-image">
  <a href="/somelink.html" class="image-hover">
    <img alt="SomeTag" src="/storage/images/100/2382.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
<figcaption class="col-xs-8">
  <h3>
    <a href="/somelink.html">
      SomeTitle
    </a>
  </h3>
  <p>
    <a href="/secondlink.html">
    SomeText
    </a>
  </p>
</figcaption>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="mobile-only icon-right">
  <a href="/somelink.html">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

I heard of jsoup but won't able to get links with jsoup.

Comment: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

Comment: Update - Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup is the best library to parse any of HTML content or document,
Here is the link and example,

http://jsoup.org/

Example

```
private void parsehtmlPage(){
        File input = new File("/yourFolder/home.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
        Element elementId = doc.getElementById("elementId");
        Elements ankerLinks = elementId.getElementsByTag("a");
        for (Element link : ankerLinks) {
            String linkHref = link.attr("href");
            String linkText = link.text();
        }
    }
```

Comment: bro what if I want to fetch data from two URLs.

Comment: You can use the same function again with your new tag, Or if you want to same then you can use for loop,

Comment: I tried but give me an error... I'm using jsoup in Async when I try to parse two links in one async app crash and if I create two async tasks it only able to parse one link